# Is this proxypass setting safe

Tags: apache, proxy, security, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I maintain a website with apache at port 80 and jboss at 8080. Additionally, I have a wordpress blog served directly from apache. So all requests to www.mysite.com/blog gets served by apache and all requests to www.mysite.com/ gets served by jboss. To enable this, I defined the following proxypass setting.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass /blog !
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/index.jsp retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/index.jsp
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Are these settings safe ? I was reading the apache documentation and they mentioned that

> Warning Do not enable proxying with ProxyRequests until you have
>   secured your server. Open proxy servers are dangerous both to your
>   network and to the Internet at large.

So I was not sure what else I need to do to make these settings safe,

Comment: probably better asked on serverfault.com, this site's sister site for sysadmins....

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt move this question. SO I accepted the answer and asked a new question in serverfault.

Comment: @fvu Please vote to migrate instead of encouraging cross-posting.

Comment: @shane one of the 2 close votes is mine, what else can I do than vote & point out the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProxyRequests is it's own command - it allows arbitary proxy connects so the client can issue something like GET http://evil.com/something.html - you should be ok with ProxyPass..